# Found a type error for plotting grap in xmgrace

Tags: python, plot, graph, typeerror, xmgrace

I found this error when I run command for plotting a graph using the `GracePlot` module in `Python`. please tell me how can i resolve it?

```
in gen_axis 

self.gen_axis('x', ax_min=xmin, ax_max=xmax, **kwargs)

in xaxis  

 minorgrid=True,minorlinestyle=lines.dotted,minorcolor=colors.blue))

 in output list.append(axis+' tick major linestyle %d' %       

 self.majorlinestyle)

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not classobj
```

Comment: This does not look like a xmgrace script. What software are you using? Please provide more details in order that someone can answer your question.

Comment: I resolved that issue thank you for giving a reply. actually there was a line.dotted missing line in my code that's why it was giving  this error..

Comment: I am glad that you solved your problem but my point was this; you have failed to mention that you are using GracePlot (http://graceplot.sourceforge.net/) anywhere in your question. In order to get help and to avoid confusing future visitors to this page you should correctly identify the software that you are using. The normal Grace scripting does not use Python. GracePlot is a Python wrapper to control Grace from a Python script.

Comment: ok i will keep it in my mind and thank you for your guidance :)